# Take two columns and write them alternatively into one column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

If I have data in two columns and now I want to make one column that writes the from row 1 column 1 into row 1 column 5 then row 1 column 2 into row 2 column 5. Please see the example below:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, something like this:

```
=INDEX($AH$2:$AI$7,ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/2,0),IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,1,2))
```

[image]

**Edit:** Or slightly shorter and not dependent on the starting row being an even row:

```
=INDEX($AH$2:$AI$7,ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/2,0),MOD(ROW(A2),2)+1)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot! If I could ask, how did you figure that out?

Comment: Glad to help. Basically, the `ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/2,0)` produces `1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, etc.` as you drag down. The `IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,1,2)` produces `1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, etc.`, based on the data starting in an even row. It's just figuring out formulas that can produce those patterns.

Answer (score 0):

worker,

if you have Kutools Add_ins it's very simple. Please refer below link to know completely.

**https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1171-convert-multiple-rows-to-single-row.html#a1**